# D3 Hierarchy chart to display by percentage

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization, hierarchical-data

I am trying to implement **`D3 Hierarchy`** chart to display data.

It was able to display data by count but unable to implement by percentage.
I am new to D3 and learning.

I Was looking up for references online and saw suggestions on making a change to Partition -

```
"var partition = d3.layout.partition()
 .value(function(d) { return d.percent; }); "
```

-Calculated the **`'percent'`** in the SQL query which retrieves data and passed it in the front end. The function calculates the sum of the percent values.

If anyone can give me some pointers on where to go with , thats helpful.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Looking at the line - https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1283663. It displays data by count. I am trying to implement by percent